# Facebook Graph API Search Page Location

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, location

Using the Facebook Graph API, is there was a way to find Facebook pages under a specific category by searching a location?

Example: If I wanted to search Brooklyn, NY and return all of the Musician Pages in that location, could I do so with the Graph API?

Comment: Did you read the [Dokumentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately "locale" parameter has been withdrawn from Search function in Graph API :/ Imho fb made huge mistake. Here is a summary: http://socialmemos.com/you-are-doing-it-wrong-facebook/